# Blank Activity Fit To Screen

Tags: android-studio

In android studio 2.1, I want to create main activity like 2. How can I do that ? Please see my attachment. Can I fix it with the exact screen size of my device just like an android game ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Simple way: in your Activity you need to extends `Activity` instead of `AppCompatActivity`:

```
public class YourActivity extends AppCompatActivity
```

==>

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity
```

Update:
put this in `onCreate()` method, to go full screen mode

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
| View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
| View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
| View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
| View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
| View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
```

Comment: Can I fit it with exact size of the screen ; where no network bars will be shown just like an android game ....